# Meaning of "Percent increase"

Tags: statistics, percentages

When someone uses the phrase "percent increase" what does that mean?

For example, if something took $4$ seconds before and now it takes $1$ second, would that be a $400$% increase?

Comment: I'm new to this stack exchange; care to clarify the down vote on the question?

Comment: I can't see a reason to down vote your question. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: If it goes from 4 to 1 it would be a $75\%$ decrease in time, or a $300\%$ increase in speed.  Usually when people talk of percent increase or decrease they are up to no good and often they are incorrect mathematically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$A$ is a $B\%$ increase over $C$ iff $100\times(A/C-1)=B$ where the minus one is because of the "increase" part (and the 100 is because of the "percent" part).

That is, 4 is a 300% increase over 1. A 0% increase over 1 would just be 1, while a 100% increase would be 2.